# .NET Core API return list and list count

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, anonymous-types

I am trying to return a complex object as a JSON with the .NET Core 2.1 API, using the OK function.

The complex object consists of an array of anonymous objects and the count of the entire unfiltered dataset.

I am using a JavaScript library that is expecting the JSON in this format:

```
{ 
  data: dataFiltered,
  count: dataUnfiltered.length
}
```

The C# filtered anonymous object looks like this:

```
var unfiltedDataCount = product.Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId).Count();
var autoCompleteData = products.Select(p => new { name = p.Name, productId = p.ProductId, categoryId = p.CategoryId}).ToList();
```

This works: native behavior

```
return Ok(autoCompleteData);
```

This does not work: Visual Studio report errors (the name "data" and "count" does not exist in the current context.)

```
return ok( new { data: autoCompleteData, count: unfiltedDataCount});
```

Comment: Perhaps you can't new-up an object in the `Ok` method? What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: `return ok( new { data =  autoCompleteData, count = unfiltedDataCount});`

Comment: @Zac it's not "in", but "before". It's ok.

Comment: Barry, what you mean _"This does not work"_? what resulting JSON is?

Comment: @vasily.sib Isn't creating an object within a method making that object with"in" it?

Comment: @JohanP thank you that worked.

Comment: @Zac sure, but he createing an object not _"within"_ a method. He creating it **before** method invokation and then pass it to the method as parameter.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of the **entire** web api method.

Comment: @BarryMSIH  check the answer as valid, so it is useful for others in your same situation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a wrong syntax.

**Incorrect**

```
return ok( new { data: autoCompleteData, count: unfiltedDataCount});
```

**Correct**

```
return ok( new { data= autoCompleteData, count= unfiltedDataCount});
```

You can see more examples here: [Anonymous types MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).

Comment: why downvote? downvoters are another example of anonymous types :)

Comment: @x-otano I love this quote. I hate down votes with no comments.